# Is there anything making PostGIS ST_INTERSECTION faster(or something wrong with my approach)?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, st

Basically I have 2 tables:

- The first is lucc gometry(about 10'000'000 rows called lucc_indicies)
- The other is fishnet grid (10'000'000 rows called cells_gba_100m)

I want to statis lucc geometry information using cells_gba_100m:
[image]

I am doing:

```
CREATE TABLE gbmi.lucc_indicies_100m AS (
  WITH clipped AS (
    SELECT
      lucc_indicies."id",
      lucc_indicies."geom",
      lucc_indicies."gridcode",
      lucc_indicies."predfloor",
      lucc_indicies."calc_lucc_area",
      lucc_indicies."building_height",
      lucc_indicies."wall_area",
      lucc_indicies."building_volume",
      cells.cell_id AS "cell_id",
      cells.cell_centroid AS "cell_centroid",
      cells.cell_geom AS "cell_geom",
      cells.cell_area AS "cell_area",
      (
        ST_DUMP(
          ST_INTERSECTION(cells.cell_geom, lucc_indicies.geom)
        )
      ).geom AS "clipped_geom"
    FROM
      public.cells_gba_100m AS cells,
      gbmi.lucc_indicies1 as lucc_indicies
    WHERE
      st_intersects(cells.cell_geom, lucc_indicies.geom)
  )
  SELECT
    *,
    ST_AREA("clipped_geom" :: geography) AS "clipped_geom_area",
    ST_PERIMETER("clipped_geom" :: geography) AS "clipped_geom_perimeter"
  FROM
    clipped
);
```

My problem is that it's taking forever.
I ran it for like 150 hours and still got nowhere.

The explain is here:
[image]

The reason I switched to PostGIS was because this data was too big to work with in QGIS. I'm wondering if I am going about this wrong or if need to make optimizations because I may have to scale this for many more regions and it would be incredibly time consuming at the rate it's going?

Comment: Please add the `explain` output of your query so we can see if your indexes are being used

Comment: thanks for your advice, i have added the explain.

Comment: The *text* of the EXPLAIN plan would be more legible. The mean number of vertices in each polygon layer should also be reported. You should **always** use `JOIN` instead of a `FROM` list. The query plan estimates 4.7x10^12 result rows -- 150 hours wouldn't be enough.

Comment: An RDB is a good choice if you need to find and process a few things out of the many, and fast. It is not a good choice if you need to process the many - most, if not all, RDBS lack the ability for distributed computing, or even proper multi-threading, mostly due to ACID transactions. Even with *only* a 1:1 overlap ratio you are asking for 10^7 geometric operations of roughly `O(n*m)` complexity! Explore cheap in-memory bbox index data structures in the programming language of your choice, and loop over the grid cells in a distributed (or at least multi-threaded) fashion.

Comment: Should be avoiding using st_intersection as its very costly. Use a case statement to find which geoms fall within the fishnet grid and not put them through st_intersection. Only the geoms that intersect should be put through it. Something like this

`case when st_within( lucc_indicies.geom,cells.cell_geom) then geom
ST_INTERSECTION(cells.cell_geom, lucc_indicies.geom) end as geom`

Comment: thanks for your advice, ziggy. but all geometries are my statistical objects，including bakground. so, maybe i can't reduce computational workload using st_within funvtion.of course, maybe i didn't get you real meaning.

Comment: Does your server have sufficient memory for the temporary `clipped` table? Consider using a materialized view for it instead. And is your server running the slow default configuration or did you tune it? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server & https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/

Comment: @ziggy is ST_Intersection really not efficiently skipping any costly computations if there is no intersection? I'd expect it to utilize spatial indexes to first determine if the geometries are disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want geometry intersection between two massive quantity of data, of course it's gonna be long... Even using an index scan for the 2nd part, you will still have n*log(m) operation at best. There is no simple way to do magically do this. Here is a few things (I assume you're trying to do a kind of urban concentration raster):

- Do your grid needs to be 100m for the whole place? maybe you can make a larger place in the countryside or something like this ? Or at least augment the size ? Augmenting the size x2 will divide the number of cells /4...
- Can you allow a little approximation ? Something I usually do to compute this kind of thing is to first transform the polygons of building in points (using their centroid for example) where I store their area and perimeter. Then the intersection is really a lot faster (obviously). It's a little less precise because a polygon crossing a border will only be counted where it is the most, but for density purpose the impact is negligeable.
- In last resort you can manually parallelize requests: cut your grid in the number of parallel computation that you want, and use for example a python code to launch parallel request on your postgres, each request treating one part of your grid. It's not always simple to do, especially because you often need to tune postgres for it to be really efficient and be sure to have enough cores and memory to do that.

Also: be aware that using the perimeter after your intersection will include the cutting of the polygon along the border, so for example if a rectangle is across a grid border you will count the border in the perimeter in both grid cell, effectively adding 2 times the red distance below, I'm not sure if it's what you want... (the solution with points doesn't have this problem):
[image: Example of grid cutting]